# android - Expandable List View Error :getChild Cause Index Array out of Bound

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, indexoutofboundsexception, expandablelistadapter

I have a problem. My expandable list view produce error when i click the group (want to open the group and show the children). Here is the log cat result.

```
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754): Process: jkos.development.sioba, PID: 15754
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754):    at jkos.development.sioba.adapter.TumbuhanObatDetailAdapter.getChild(TumbuhanObatDetailAdapter.java:49)
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754):    at jkos.development.sioba.adapter.TumbuhanObatDetailAdapter.getChildView(TumbuhanObatDetailAdapter.java:95)
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754):    at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2257)
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
09-24 01:44:47.987: E/AndroidRuntime(15754):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16525)
```

here is my adapter class

```
public class TumbuhanObatDetailAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private ArrayList<String> listHeader;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listItem;

public TumbuhanObatDetailAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> listHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listItem){
    this._context = context;
    this.listHeader = listHeader;
    this.listItem = listItem;
}
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.listHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.listItem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.listHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return this._listItem.get(this._listHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    return this.listItem.get(listHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.tumbuhanobatdetailgroupitem, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandableListViewHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;


    //return null;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //System.out.println("group : "+groupPosition+" child : "+childPosition);

    String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.tumbuhanobatdetailchilditem, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childItem);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;

    //return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
```

}

here is a section where adapter is called in my java activity

```
    ArrayList<String>listHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, List<String>>listItem = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    listHeader.add("Umum");
    listHeader.add("Simplisia");
    listHeader.add("Kegunaan Empiris");


    List<String> umum = new ArrayList<String>();
    umum.add(namaIndonesia);
    umum.add(namaLatin);

    List<String> simplisia = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < namaSimplisia.size(); i++){
        simplisia.add(namaSimplisia.get(i));
    }

    List<String> penggunaanEmpiris = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < kegunaanEmpiris.size(); i++){
        penggunaanEmpiris.add(kegunaanEmpiris.get(i));
    }

    listItem.put(listHeader.get(0), umum);
    listItem.put(listHeader.get(1), simplisia);
    listItem.put(listHeader.get(2), penggunaanEmpiris);

    tumbuhanObatDetailAdapter = new TumbuhanObatDetailAdapter(context, listHeader, listItem);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(tumbuhanObatDetailAdapter);
```

Please i need an answer as soon as possible

Comment: What debugging have you done before posting here? Set any breakpoints?

Comment: I just try to know what is the groupposition and childposition value that cause an index out of bound exception. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Change your getChildrenCount() code to this:

```
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.listItem.get(groupPosition).size();
}
```

You are giving the size of complete hashmap as the count of children in the particular group. Thats why it is causing IndexOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score 0):

The array is 0-indexed - meaning that the array contains object 0 and object 1, not object 1 and object 2, so just remove 1 before you call your function

Change this

```
String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
```

to this

```
String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition - 1, childPosition);
```

Comment: Which array and how to remove it ? Please give me some of codes to clear understanding. Thank you. :)